# How in PyQt put multiple DockWidgets off grid pattern

Tags: pyqt

All methods known to me for arranging dock widgets allow them to be combined according to the grid pattern. But I would like to arrange them as in the schematic example below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdCWg.png)

I tryed to use Qt.DockWidgetArea flags and also splitDockWidget method of QMainWindow

Comment: See the [`QMainWindow.setCorner()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCorner) documentation: `mainWindow.setCorner(Qt.BottomRightCorner, Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)`.